# using repeat helper within a dom-bind template

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am new to polymer and I'm still just kind of trying to get my groove, but I'm stuck.

I have the following code (this is in the main document):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client.js"></script>
<template id="banner" is="dom-bind"> 
  <page-section>
    <section-title value="Banner"></section-title>    
    <section-content>
      <script> console.log(CLIENT); </script>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{CLIENT.sections}}">
        <span>{{item.title}}</span>
      </template>
    </section-content>
  </page-section>
</template>
```

This is `client.js`:

```
var CLIENT = (function () { 
  return Object.freeze({
    sections: [ 
      {title:"hello", id:"blah"}, 
      {title:"goodbye", id:"foo"}
    ]});
}());
```

I know that CLIENT is being loaded, because the array is logged to console, but no spans are being rendered onto the page. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are there any (error) messages in the console (F12)?

Comment: no, only the CLIENT object is logged. I am using Chrome v44

Comment: How about {{CLIENT.sections.title}} ?

Comment: @neolace as the value of items? This doesn't work, but I wouldn't expect it to. The docs say that the value of `items` should be an array

Comment: your inner template needs an "   as="item" inside of the tag along with items=

Comment: @RobertRowntree I'm a little confused. I can't find mention of this in the docs, can you point me to some reference material?

Comment: #111 in   https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/master/demo/index.html

Comment: @RobertRowntree I am not using Iron-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `as="item"` as `item` is the default name of the array item. But you need to make sure that web components are ready and assign the right data to your `#banner` template.

So in your `client.js` file, do this -

```
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady',function(){
  document.querySelector('#banner').CLIENT =
    Object.freeze({ 
      sections: [ 
        {title:"hello", id:"blah"}, 
        {title:"goodbye", id:"foo"}
      ]});
});
```

Have a look at a working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jlIhKgVzePcnQC8ZrLRX?p=preview).

Comment: So I can only use data that is a property on the template element? My goal was to be able to have a single model that multiple elements could use as their data source. Under the paradigm presented by your example, I would have to copy the `sections` object as a property on every element that wanted to use it. What is the best practice for this?

Comment: That's how you bind the `template` to the data, otherwise how does it know what data to use? If you want multiple templates with the same data, you can always define the data once and assign it to multiple templates (see http://plnkr.co/edit/8XQYn1bwJLGik5oFqwcs?p=preview).

Comment: Its just doesn't feel optimal, everytime I add a template I have to remember to bind data to it in some other file. Im just wondering why, since `CLIENT` is a global variable, why can't the template find it?

Comment: I guess I can just make a class, like `data_consumer` and put it on all the templates that need it.

Comment: The data binding and all the Polymer goodies are available *within* the template. Outside of it, it's just plain HTML. So I don't think the data will just flow down to the template. And yes, you absolutely can.